# Как исправить ошибку подключения socket.io на import

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-modules

У меня есть код, который запрашивает у пользователя пароль, но после изменения require на import, socket.io перестал находить файл, пытался менять href скрипта в html на cdn, но всё равно ничего не работает
Код:
index.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
const app = express();
import http from 'http';
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import fs from 'fs';

const io = new Server(http, {
    
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join('./views'));

var password = "1111"

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join('./public')));
var checkIp4;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        if (data.text == password) {
            console.log('password send, true');
            checkedIpAdress.push(checkIp4);
            fs.appendFile('./logs/checkedIpAdress.log', `${checkIp4}\n`, (err) => {
                err ? true : false
            });
        } else {
            console.log('password send, false');
            console.log('false ip4: ');
            console.log(checkIp4);
            fs.appendFile('./logs/connections.log', `connection, false password ${checkIp4}`, (err) => {
                err ? true : false
            });
        }
    })
});
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('askPassword');
})

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(404).render('404');
});

var port = 3000;

server.listen(port);
console.log('Started!');
```

askPassword.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Запрос доступа</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h4 class="mb-3">Требуется проверка пароля</h4>
    <form id="needmees">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label for="text class=" form-label">Введите пароль:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control w-50 mb-2" id="text-mess-ok" placeholder="Пароль...">
        </div>
        <button class="w-50 btn btn-primary btn-lg submit-message" type="button">Войти</button>
    </form>


    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect();
        var $form = $('#needmees');
        var $input = $('#text-mess-ok');

        let sended = false;

        $('.submit-message').on('click', () => {
            if (sended) return;
            sended = true;
            socket.emit('send', { text: $input.val() });
            $input.val('');
            sended = false;
            window.location.reload();   
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Какие файлы не находятся? Какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: Не находит файл socket.io.js
Ошибка: 
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Так это вам не сокет выдает, а похоже что вот это `app.get('*'`

Comment: Я уже исправил ошибку, заменил начальные строки на вот эти:

import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
const app = express();
import http from 'http';
const server = http.createServer(app);
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import fs from 'fs';


const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    }
});